# Office JavaScript API: Binding a substring of the selection

Tags: office-js

## Problem

Using the Office JavaScript API in MS Word, I know how to bind the current selection using `document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync`, however, I have not found a way to bind a substring of the current selection.

For example, if the user selected an entire paragraph and I would like to bind the first word only, how would I be able to do this?

## Failed approaches

1. First binding the selection, then binding a substring, and then removing the first binding: I have not found a way to bind a substring.
2. First changing the selection and then using `addFromSelectionAsync`: I have not found a way to change the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word a **Binding** is physically represented by a content control within the document, so in general the approach is to create the content control where you need it (in this case the first word in the selection) and assign a title to it, so that finally you can create the binding using bindings.addFromNamedItem method.

In summary:

1. Get the Range where you want to create the binding. on this case you want the first word within the selection.
2. Once you have the range, wrap it with a content control and assign a title.
3. Finally, use the addFromNamedItem using that title.

Here is a sample:

```js
 Word.run(function (context) {
        //first we get the first word in the selection by using the split method, and using space as delimiter and then we add a content control
        var firstWordContentControl = context.document.getSelection().split([" "], true, false, true).getFirst().insertContentControl();
//let's add a title.
        firstWordContentControl.title = "BindingID";
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () { 
//we reuse the title to create the binding.
                Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("BindingID", "text", {}, function (result) {
                    console.log(result.status);
                    if (result.status == "succeeded") { 
                        // lets create an event!
                        result.value.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, function () { 
                            console.log("event happened");
                        })
                    }
                 });
            })
    })
        .catch(function(exception) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(exception);
    })
```

Hope this helps.
-Juan

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly what you're looking for, the [Word API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview) gives you most of what you'd need to accomplish this.

The user's current selection can be fetched using [document.getSelection()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document#getselection). This returns a [Range object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range). From here you can drill into [Paragraphs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraphcollection.htm), [child ranges](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range#getnexttextrangeendingmarks-string-trimspacing-bool) (based on word-break rules) and so on.

Once you have a Range object that reflects the text you're looking for, [range.Select()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range#selectselectionmode-string) will cause that range to be selected in the UI. From here you can use `addFromSelectionAsync` to establish your binding.